# Can we define new $\mathsf{LTL}$-operators working in the past?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to define some new macros in $\mathsf{LTL}$ as follows:

- $\mathsf S$ince should describe that some formulae $\varphi$ is valid since some point where $\psi$ has been valid:
  $$w,x \models \varphi\mathsf S \psi \iff \exists z: w,z \models \psi \land \forall y: y> z \land w,y \models \varphi  $$
- $\mathsf Y$esterday should describe that some $\varphi$ is valid one position before the current one and can be understood as the complement of $\mathsf X$ which is the NEXT-operator. I've tried to define it as follows:
  $$w,x \models \mathsf Y\varphi \iff  w, \mathsf Yx \models \varphi \iff w, x - 1 \models \varphi$$

**Question:**

1. Are operators that use the past to make some statement,"valid" and useable in $\mathsf{LTL}$? When reading the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic) on $\mathsf{LTL}$, I couldn't find any operators that work with the past in that direct way.
2. Are there any problems with my definition of those operators?

Comment: Extending LTL with the inverse of NEXT (aka Yesterday) is quite standard. There is, most certainly, a plethora of papers on particular issues of past-LTL you may be interested in. For example, succinctness is discussed in https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01194627/document
You can also check out textbook **Temporal Logics in Computer Science**, Chapter 6.5 for an introduction.

Comment: Ui nice! Thanks a lot! If you like to make it an answer I'd be happy to upvote and mark as correct :)

Comment: cheers! I think I am happy with the upvoted comment.